# Using generic function does not work for loading YAML list with jackson

Tags: generics, kotlin, jackson, yaml

I just recently started trying out Kotlin and I'm mostly amazed with it so far. However, I can't quite wrap my head around how the generics work here.

I want to read a YAML file that looks like this:

```
- id: acrobatics
  name: Akrobatik
  description:
  ...
```

A simple data class to map this to:

```
data class Skill (
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

Now, on to the interesting part. **Apparently, it does work with generics!**
I started with this function, which does its job as intended:

```
fun loadSkills(): List<Skill> {

    val resource: URL = classLoader.getResource("rulebook/skills.yml")!!

    val items: List<Skill> = resource.openStream()
        .bufferedReader().use() { reader ->
            objectMapper.readValue<List<Skill>>(reader)
        }

    return items
}
```

However, I want to reuse this, so I tried creating a generic function:

```
protected fun <R: Any> loadList(path: String): List<R> {

    val resource: URL = classLoader.getResource(path)!!

    val items: List<R> = resource.openStream()
        .bufferedReader().use() { reader ->
            objectMapper.readValue<List<R>>(reader)
        }

    return items
}
```

And my original function just calls:

```
return loadList<Skill>("rulebook/skills.yml")
```

And now my tests fail because I get a List of LinkedHashMaps, which seems to be the default datatype used by the YAML parser to map objects.
I read a little more and tried changing my method signature to an inline function with a reified type parameter:

```
protected inline fun <reified R: Any> loadList(path: String): List<R>
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything.
Is there any way to make this work elegantly?

Comment: try replacing reader with it objectMapper.readValue<List<R>>(it) without the lambda

Comment: I tried. Doesn't change anything. But I would have been more confused if it did.

Answer (score 1):

Since all generic type information does not exist at runtime, you need to provide it to Jackson somehow. Reified type keeps that information, but AFAIK Jackson does not use it so you have to do it manually. For example, like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> loadSkills(path: String): List<T> {

    val resource: URL = javaClass.classLoader.getResource(path)
    val type = objectMapper.typeFactory.constructParametricType(List::class.java, T::class.java)
    val items: List<T> = resource.openStream()
                .bufferedReader().use { reader ->
                    objectMapper.readValue(reader, type)
                }

    return items
}
```

**EDIT**: It turns out that there is a restriction in jackson-kotlin-module for automatic calculation of nested generic types. 
If you try to parse yaml (or whatever else) for single Skill (without list) it will work properly even inside generic function, but once you want to have nesting like List< Skill >, it fails to recognise type properly and produces List of HashMaps

Comment: I assumed that, too. But shouldn't my first solution fail for the same reason?

Comment: No, first solution works because you have type information (Skill.class) in bytecode and Jackson uses it for deserialization. With generics you don't have such information.

Comment: But... aren't both solutions effectively using the same generics?

Comment: Oh you mean first solution with generics does work? I understood that only non-generic solution works (and I've tried it). Only it should work without providing additional type info to objectMapper's readValue method.

Comment: I might have to make it clearer, but yes, the first method which uses <Skill> as generic does work. And I assumed reifiying R would essentially do the same.

Comment: In fact this is interesting question, because readValue from kotlin module is inline function with reified type parameter: 
inline fun <reified T> ObjectMapper.readValue(src: Reader): T = readValue(src, jacksonTypeRef<T>()). So it is expected to work as you assumed, but in fact it does not. I need a little bit more investigation on this, but it looks like reified type parameters do not pass to nested inline functions.

Comment: After a little investigation it turned out that if you have nested generic class or interface passed to readValue from jackson-kotlin-module, information about nested type parameter is getting erased and we just get java.util.List<? extends T> type  which results in calling jackson's readValue with this type and produces List of hashmaps as output. You can actually debug this method to see whats happening in details, but it looks like a restriction (or bug?) of jackson-kotlin-module. So atm to achieve your goal you need to calculate type manually and pass it to readValue method from java lib.